# Почему html вид django отличается от того же запущенного файла

Tags: html, css, django

Я долго ничего не понимал: почему код css был, но он не выполнялся, хотя всё проверял? Решил запустить просто файл html без сервера django, и он сработал. Стили применились. Из-за чего это произошло и как это исправить?

Скрин с сервером Django
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Скрин без него
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>SOME</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootcss\bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container some">
    <div class="row some">
        <div class="col">Hello</div>
      <div class="col">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="mySQLServer">Enter name of SQL server </label> 
            <input id="mySQLServer" type="text" name="mySQLServer" maxlength="100" required />
            <label for="myDataBase">Enter name of Database </label> 
            <input id="mySQLDataBase" type="text" name="mySQLDataBase" maxlength="100" required />
        </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
        <div class="col">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Код CSS:

```
.some {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: В ссылках не должен использоваться \ — должен быть всегда только /

Comment: _<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootcss\bootstrap.css">_ Это тут? В любом случае основная часть лежит в css, да и столбики-то работают как надо. Всё меняет @andreymal

Comment: Да, тут, в любом случае \ использоваться не должен (даже если это вдруг не причина проблемы)

Comment: Расскажите, как вы запускаете сервер Django, откройте мониторинг сети в браузере, посмотрите, есть ли какие-то ошибки, открываются ли стили по этим ссылкам

Comment: Если вдруг вы ожидаете, что Django будет раздавать файлы из того каталога, в котором запущена, то нет, Django не занимается раздачей файлов

Comment: python manage.py runserver 0:8000;Нет, всё в порядке  в мониторинге сетей. @andreymal

Comment: Что именно всё в порядке? Файлы стилей загружаются без ошибок, значит? И по ссылке из того же мониторинга сети тоже открываются?

Comment: Да именно так. Так же нет сообщений об ошибках и предостережениях(если я верно перевёл). Да и если бы были с сервером django, то и были бы без него  @andreymal

Comment: @Pashok а если в браузере открыть http://localhost:8000/bootcss/bootstrap.css, то что выведет?

Comment: Не удаётся получить доступ к сайту.       Что за магия?         Я пока запутался.     Можете подсказать из-за чего это происходит?     Просто я запускаю один и тот же файл разными способами(django  и просто через chrome) и получаю разный результат @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: @Pashok Django-сервер не имеет никакого отношения к открытию файлов. Если вы не настраивали его специально на раздачу файлу, он не будет раздавать файлы. Покажите скриншот мониторинга сети во время открытия страницы через Django-сервер, а то я вам не очень верю

Comment: Возможно я не правильно объяснил. Не открывает, а показывает(выводит в браузере разный результат) @andreymal

Comment: Решение через static помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе нужно создать папку static в директории приложения и в неё скинуть CSS файл. Затем в HTML файле в самой первой строчке напиши `{% load static %}` и строку `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootcss\bootstrap.css">` замени на `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap.css' %}">`. Если не работает то проверь INSTALLED_APPS в файле settings.py, в этом списке должно быть твое приложение.

Надеюсь помогло.